# Find the arc length of a circle

Tags: geometry, circles

Question:
In a circle of diameter 40 cm, the length of a chord is 20 cm. Find the length of minor arc of the chord.

My Workout:
Chord of length 40 cm has arc length of semicircle curcumference i.e = π × 20 = 20π CM

So chord of length 10 CM has (proportionately) length = 10π cm

Answer (given):
20π / 3

Why am I wrong

Comment: The arc length is not proportional to the chord length.

Comment: The chord length and radius are of equal length so the chord and two radii form an equilateral triangle. Therefore, the arc length is one sixth of the circumference which is $40\pi$. That's how they get $\frac{40\pi}{6}=\frac{20\pi}{3}$.

Answer (score 2):

In order to find a length of an arc of a given chord, you should determine what the angle $\angle AOB$ formed by the center $O$ of the circle with radius 20 cm and the two end points of the chord $AB$. Here lies the real proportionality, that is, the length of this arc $\newcommand{arc}[1]{\stackrel{\Large\frown}{#1}}\arc{AB}$ to the circumference of the circle is equal to the angle $\angle AOB$ to the measure of the whole circle, i.e., $360^{\circ}$ or $2\pi$. Hence,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\newcommand{arc}[1]{\stackrel{\Large\frown}{#1}}\arc{AB}}{2\pi r}=\frac{\angle AOB}{2\pi}.
\end{align*}
Simplifying and solving for $\newcommand{arc}[1]{\stackrel{\Large\frown}{#1}}\arc{AB}$ we get
\begin{align*}
\newcommand{arc}[1]{\stackrel{\Large\frown}{#1}}\arc{AB}=r\angle AOB_{\text{rad}}.
\end{align*}
Since $AB=AO=OB=r=20$ cm, then $\triangle AOB$ is equilateral, and thus $\angle AOB=\frac{\pi}{3}$. Substituting gives the result
\begin{align*}
\newcommand{arc}[1]{\stackrel{\Large\frown}{#1}}\arc{AB}=\frac{20\pi}{3}.
\end{align*}
[A circle with radius 20 cm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWbKq.png)

Comment: Possible MathJax alternative: `$\overset{\Huge\frown}{ABC}$` and `$\overset{\huge\frown}{AB}$`

Answer (score 1):

> Why am I wrong

I don't know because your work seems like guesswork and possibly not related to the problem, since the chord in the problem and your chord ($20 \not = 10$) are of different length.

Regardless, we continue. Our circle has a diameter of $40$ and a radius of $20$ by definition. We may then realize that our chord is of equal length to the radius of our circle, meaning our chord can be formed by an angle of $60^o$ or $\frac{\pi}{3}$. There are two ways you can see this,

- first as suggested in the comments you can form an equilateral triangle with the two intersections of the chord and the circle with the center, and thus you have $\frac{\pi}{3}$ radians for an angle.
- Second, we can do this formulaically. The formula for a chord length is
  $$2r \sin(\frac{\theta}{2}) = L$$
  Where $r$ is the radius of the circle, $\theta$ is the angle, and $L$ is the length of the chord. Then, we can find through manipulation that $\theta = 2 \sin^{-1}(\frac{1}{2}) = 2 \frac{\pi}{6} = \frac{\pi}{3}$.

Now that we have our angle, we can easily find the arc length using the formula:
$$A = \theta r = \frac{pi}{3} \cdot 20 = \frac{20 \pi}{3}$$
And thus we have obtained our answer.